# select xml element from web.xml using xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, web.xml, xmlstarlet

I'm using xmlstarlet to select values from web.xml. It is not working and returns nothing.
If my web.xml contains following properties:

```
<web-app version="2.4"
   xmlns="java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
   xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
```

command I'm executing

```
xml select -t -v "web-app/display-name" web.xml
```

How can i ignore above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following and succeeded

```
xml sel -N x="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" -t  -v "x:web-app/x:security-role" /root/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have version 1.5.0, the default namespace (`java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee` in this case) is automatically given the prefix `_`, so `-N` is not needed:

```
xml sel -t -v "_:web-app/_:security-role" /root/WEB-INF/web.xml
```